# FedEx API merge PDFs (Shipping Labels) PHP

Tags: php, api, fedex

Is there a way to merge shipping labels or append another shipping label to another in the FedEx API? I've tried the following but have had no success

```
//Create the shipping label in the provided file SHIP_LABEL
$label= $response->CompletedShipmentDetail->CompletedPackageDetails->Label->Parts->Image;
$fp = fopen(SHIP_LABEL, 'wb');
fwrite($fp, $label);
fclose($fp);

//Append the second shipping label
$label2= $response2->CompletedShipmentDetail->CompletedPackageDetails->Label->Parts->Image;
$fp = fopen(SHIP_LABEL, 'a');
fwrite($fp, $label2);
fclose($fp);
```

We have no need of storing labels other than for creating children labels that follow the master tracking number.. If I could use something like the above method I could make them all at once and still only use 1 pdf that I can overwrite every time we create a new label(s)